# Getting information from "users" table about users who I'm friends with. relational/join SQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, relational

So I'm trying to make a social media kinda feature where you're on a user's profile and you can see a list of his friends with their profile picture and their name like this:

[image: Page layout]

The SQL tables I'm dealing with are the "**users**" table and the "**friendships**" table:

[image: Friendships table]

**"users" Table:**

[image]

How do I fetch the first_name, last_name and user_avatar information from the friends of the user who's page I'm currently on?

(I have the `UserID` of the user who's page I'm currently on stored in a variable called `$UserID`. and let's say currently `$UserID = 1`)

Comment: the "current" user is intended as "accepter" in your `friendships` table?

Comment: How exactly are the two tables related?

Comment: @PM77-1 RequesterID and AccepterID correspond to some user's UserID in the 'users' table

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest The current user can be either AccepterID or RequesterID

Comment: @FreddyErichsen, so what do `RequesterID` and `AccepterID` mean in your concept? which one is "friend" for the current user?

Comment: RequesterID is the friend who sent the friend request and AccepterID is the one who accepted it. It's just a little more descriptive than user_1 and user_2 or friend_1 and friend_2 or something.

Answer (score 0):

To get user's friends info use the following query(if the "current" user is intended as "accepter" in `friendships` table):

```
// php code: $userID = 1;

SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name, u.user_avatar
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN friendships AS fr ON fr.RequesterID = u.UserID
WHERE fr.AccepterID = $userID AND fr.friendship_active = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the "current" user can be either AccepterID or RequesterID, making the query a lot more complicated I guess.